# What does "the market face" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning

i am not english native speaker, i am italian.

I couldn't find a definition online.

---

What does "the market face" mean in this passage?

> A very significant role of the clearing house is managing the risk
>   created by the transactions on the exchange. From setting the criteria
>   for membership of the clearing house to establishing default rules,
>   using margin systems and requiring daily settlement of resulting
>   obligations of all members,  the clearing house controls the risk that
>   the exchange, the members and the users of **the market face**.

Comment: Consider that _face_ is a verb here. Now consider a sentence such as: _"These are the risks that you and I face."_ Can you understand that sentence? Do you understand that _**the market face**_ is _not_ a noun phrase?

Comment: @P.E.Dant It sounds like you've got an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Please don't closevote this question. This kind of thing can be very hard for non-native speakers to figure out, even with the aid of a dictionary. If your native language doesn't use attributive nouns, or uses them very differently than English, trying to figure them out in English can be very confusing. And then you hit a passage like this, where "the market face" _doesn't_ have an attributive noun even though it looks like one!

Answer (score 2):

In that sentence, **face** is a verb. Its subject is "the exchange, the members and the users of **the market**." Its object is **risk**, from earlier in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> the users of the market **face**

**face** has the meaning "**exposed to**", as in "

> come **face to face**
>
> the clearing house controls the risk that the users of the market **are exposed to**

Comment: "Exposed to" is a great way to explain the meaning of "face" in this context. However, I don't think it has the same meaning as "come face-to-face".